# Generating random HearthStone cards: Preparing the training data

Tags: json, groovy

For a little toy project of mine I need to have data available in a certain format in order to be able to feed into a Recurrent Neural Network (Long short term memory), it uses HearthStone card data that is available in JSON format.

Example input:

```
{
    "id":"EX1_306",
    "name":"Succubus",
    "type":"Minion",
    "faction":"Neutral",
    "rarity":"Free",
    "cost":2,
    "attack":4,
    "health":3,
    "text":"<b>Battlecry:</b> Discard a random card.",
    "flavor":"Warlocks have it pretty good.",
    "artist":"Matt Dixon",
    "collectible":true,
    "race":"Demon",
    "playerClass":"Warlock",
    "howToGet":"Unlocked at Level 1.",
    "howToGetGold":"Unlocked at Level 40.",
    "mechanics":[
        "Battlecry"
    ]
}
```

Example output:

```
Basic | Spell | Common | Paladin | Blessing of Kings | 4 | Give a minion +4/+4. <i>(+4 Attack/+4 Health)</i>
Classic | Minion | Legendary | Neutral | Dragon | Onyxia | 9 | 8 | 8 | <b>Battlecry:</b> Summon 1/1 Whelps until your side of the battlefield is full.
Basic | Minion | Free | Neutral | Beast | River Crocolisk | 2 | 2 | 3 | 
Basic | Weapon | Free | Warrior | Fiery War Axe | 2 | 3 | 2 | 
Classic | Minion | Legendary | Neutral | Pirate | Captain Greenskin | 5 | 5 | 4 | <b>Battlecry:</b> Give your weapon +1/+1.
Classic | Minion | Legendary | Neutral | None | Tinkmaster Overspark | 3 | 3 | 3 | <b>Battlecry:</b> Transform another random minion into a 5/5 Devilsaur or a 1/1 Squirrel.
Goblins vs Gnomes | Minion | Common | Neutral | Mech | Flying Machine | 3 | 1 | 4 | <b>Windfury</b>
```

Please note that the example input describes only a single card, while the example output describes an unrelated set of cards.

I decided to implement this in Groovy, and am looking forward to receiving lots of feedback as this is the first standalone program I've written in Groovy.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption

/**
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
class Main {
    static String cardDataUrl = "http://hearthstonejson.com/json/AllSets.json"
    static Path targetPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "HearthStoneTrainData", "data.txt")
    static long targetFileSize = 1024L * 1024L

    static void main(String[] args) {
        saveToTargetFile(convertToOneLiners(splitIntoSets(retrieveCardData())))
    }

    static Object retrieveCardData() {
        JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        jsonSlurper.parse(new URL(cardDataUrl), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
    }

    static Map<String, List> splitIntoSets(Object cardsJson) {
        def map = new HashMap()
        cardsJson.each { set, cards ->
            map[set] = cards
        }
        map
    }

    static List<String> convertToOneLiners(Map<String, List> cardsBySet) {
        def list = new ArrayList()
        cardsBySet.each { set, cards ->
            cards.each { card ->
                if (card.collectible) {
                    list.add(convertToOneLiner(set, card))
                }
            }
        }
        list
    }

    static String convertToOneLiner(String set, Object cardJson) {
        def type = cardJson.type
        def rarity = cardJson.rarity ?: "Token"
        def race = cardJson.race ?: "None"
        def playerClass = cardJson.playerClass ?: "Neutral"
        def name = cardJson.name
        def cost = cardJson.cost
        def attack = cardJson.attack
        def health = cardJson.health
        def durability = cardJson.durability
        def text = cardJson.text ?: ""
        switch (type) {
            case "Minion":
                return "${set} | ${type} | ${rarity} | ${playerClass} | ${race} | ${name} | ${cost} | ${attack} | ${health} | ${text}"
            case "Spell":
                return "${set} | ${type} | ${rarity} | ${playerClass} | ${name} | ${cost} | ${text}"
            case "Enchantment":
                return "${set} | ${type} | ${playerClass} | ${text}"
            case "Weapon":
                return "${set} | ${type} | ${rarity} | ${playerClass} | ${name} | ${cost} | ${attack} | ${durability} | ${text}"
            case "Hero":
                return "${set} | ${type} | ${rarity} | ${playerClass} | ${name} | ${health}"
            case "Hero Power":
                return "${set} | ${type} | ${rarity} | ${playerClass} | ${name} | ${cost} | ${text}"
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: ${type} in ${cardJson}")
        }
    }

    static void saveToTargetFile(List<String> cardOneLiners) {
        def copyCardOneLiners = new ArrayList(cardOneLiners)
        Files.deleteIfExists(targetPath)
        Files.createFile(targetPath)
        def writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
        writer.withCloseable {
            while (targetPath.size() < targetFileSize) {
                println("Progress: ${targetPath.size()}/${targetFileSize}")
                Collections.shuffle(copyCardOneLiners)
                copyCardOneLiners.each { line ->
                    writer.append(line)
                    writer.newLine()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks pretty groovy to me. I only have some minor nitpicks.

Instead of `def map = new HashMap()`, you can write simpler as `def map = [:]`

Likewise, instead of `def list = new ArrayList()`, you can write `def list = []`

As of Groovy 1.8, the `splitIntoSets` method can be simplified with `collectEntries`:

```
static Map<String, List> splitIntoSets(Object cardsJson) {
    cardsJson.collectEntries { it }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Main` is not a very good name for a class. Not even if it is a main class. Summarize what your code does.

Additionally, you could write this as a pure Groovy script without wrapping everything explicitly in a class ([as others have done](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96740/31562)). Judging by what your main method does, it seems to be a pretty straight-forward, do A, do B, do C, do D.

```
saveToTargetFile(convertToOneLiners(splitIntoSets(retrieveCardData())))
```

---

When using variable interpolation you don't need to write `${variable}`, simply using `$variable` is enough.

```
return "${set} | ${type} | ${rarity} | ${playerClass} | ${race} | ${name} | ${cost} | ${attack} | ${health} | ${text}"
```

can become:

```
return "$set | $type | $rarity | $playerClass | $race | $name | $cost | $attack | $health | $text"
```